# Menu Header item background color

Tags: html, css, shopify

Im trying to add a background color behind the "store" menu item however I have tried many ways and are not able to only make the "store" item change the background.
background color change to: #37bbec, and also change the font color to #fff.
[image]
I have attached a image of the menu item I wish to change.

Comment: DO YOU WANT TO GET HACKED. Delete that password immediately. Use a fiddle here to show us the code: https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @StevenMays, I think the password is just for access to the public site, not the server. I don't think it's a big deal. I put simple password protection on new sites, as well.. Also, in the event the password does open the door to sensitive data, deleting it wouldn't do anything here. The edit history retains all information. He would have to delete the entire question.

Comment: Its just a top level password to the actual front end site, But thanks for the concern neither less :)

Comment: @David, one purpose of Stack Overflow is to create a repository of questions and answers that can help people in the future. That's why we ask you to post your code. Posting a link isn't useful because once your problem is resolved, the link will be useless, and the question won't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

As a general principle, you could target it with this basic construct:

```
ul li:first-child a:first-child { … }
```

But you can deal with ids, classes and specificity as needed.

Comment: With the bracket { ... } would that be number 1 as it represents the first header item ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but I did a quick test on your site before the link disappeared, and I just put the styles you wanted inside those brackets—something like `.nav li:first-child a:first-child {color: #fff; background: #37bbec;}`. But you'd need `!important` on each of those currently, because this rule isn't specific enough to override current styles otherwise, so it would need a higher specificity to work without `!important`.